# NodeJS: Is there a way to stream a file from another server without piping through mine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a site in which I provide links for download/streaming for media files on another server.
Currently how I have it setup is that something similar to the following:

```
download = (req, res) ->
  song_id = req.params.id
  download_url = "http://mediaserver.com/#{song_id}"
  console.log("Returning download from: #{download_url}")
  res.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
  res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="download.mp3"')
  request.get(download_url).pipe(res)
  #For some reason, express.js on a response end event emits a finish
  #http://www.samcday.com.au/blog/2011/06/27/listening-for-end-of-response-with-nodeexpress-js/
  res.on "finish", ()->
    console.log("Completed song download")
```

However, I'm looking for a way I can just return a HTTP response object that tells the browser to just download it from the appropriate server instead of my own? (possibly still changing the HTTP headers to allow the file to be saved as a download).

Any way this is possible?

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a 301 (permanent) or 302 (temporary) redirect with a location header.

```
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'http://someUrlHere'
});
```

I'm not an Express user, but it looks like you can set the status code in Express with `res.send(302)`.

Comment: But i'd like the file to come up as a download or to be able to stream it. Can I still do with with a 301 or 302?

Comment: @Setheron, What to do with the resource is entirely up to the browser, whether you serve the file or someone else does.  Yes, of course you can still stream it.  As far as it coming up as a download depends on if the user's browser will open that resource by default or not.  No, you will not be able to set a `Content-Disposition` header on a resource not served by you.

Comment: The reason I was piping it so far was so I can set the content disposition (as you can see in my example). The problem is I was hoping for a download button experience... i guess there doesn't seem to be a way to do it unless I pipe it through myself.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you won't be able to set headers for that resource on another server.  I'm afraid if you want to guarantee that the browser will download it, you will have to pipe it through.  Another thing you can do to save bandwidth is check the response headers from that remote server to see if they are already including the `Content-Disposition` header, forcing a download.  If so, then just redirect.  Otherwise, pipe.

Comment: oh that's a fairly good idea! Are you aware of any javascript client side libraries that force the save as button? I know firefox has browser specific API but I couldn't find anything browser agnostic.

Comment: @Setheron, No, I don't believe there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply provide the links to the server hosting the actual files, then the browser will download them when clicked?

e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.assets.com/file.mp3">File</a>
```

Comment: A simple link does not change whether or not a browser will download, or attempt to open the resource.  That's up to the browser, which can be influenced by the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: Right, I think I understand what the Op is trying to do now. Force the download behaviour right? Then I agree with you, only real way to add the headers is to proxy the request yourself if the origin server does not have the Content-Disposition header.